# Writing own installer "creator" in C#

Tags: c#, installation, zip

I'm not that long into programming, so excuse me if that's an stupid question.

I know there are several setup creators out there, like the default Visual Studio Installer Project, InstallShield, NSIS etc., but I thought that it would be cool if I have my own solution.

Let's say I would like to make my own installer creator, a tool where I can add several files I'd like to install and defining an own script system (propably XML-based). Creating a tool that packs all the files I added to.. let's say a zip is an easy step. But how am I able to develop something that builds an executable? How is this being achieved?

Any advices and helpful tips are appreciated!

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel - just use Wix (http://wixtoolset.org/).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by writing your own?

Comment: Should your executable be a .net application or win32 (runnable without .net being installed)?

Comment: Installers go from a simple concept, to an insane number of things you have to worry about. Like @ShellShock says, stick with WiX - as it covers a lot of these concerns for you. You have pretty much described WiX anyway -- `probably XML-based`.

Comment: @ShellShock I do want to reinvent the wheel for the sake of learning. ;)

Comment: @CubeSchrauber .net will be fine! The applications I try to distribute depend on .net anyway.

Comment: It sounds counterintuitive, but you will actually learn much more by reading other people's code. Reading other people's code is more common and more difficult.

Comment: @Neurodefekt I did this also and i don't regret it. But it was a lot of work. My installer is able to install the framework and therefore cannot be written in C#. As already answered binary data can be appended to a native .exe. Within .Net this would more resemble an managed resource. But probably the same trick works here also.

Comment: @CubeSchrauber Yes, I also thought about storing some basic code in a text file and compile it on the fly using System.CSharp namespace classes. But if I would want to have a GUI, and now think of all the designer code, this approach seems ridiculous to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure wether that satisfies your needs. This is how i append some data to a file named `filename` based on an executable named `BaseExecutable`. The data could be a .zip or anything else. The `BaseExecutable` is some sort of installer (in my case a Win32 executable) which reads the appended data from **itself**. Starting location of the data can be found at positions 44,45,46,47 of the resulting executable. I didn't try that with any .NET exe

```
public void Create(string Filename, string BaseExecutable)
{
    FileStream Source = new FileStream(BaseExecutable, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);

    file = new FileStream(Filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
    Source.Read(buffer, 0, 48);
    file.Write(buffer, 0, 44);

    writer = new BinaryWriter(file, Encoding.ASCII);
    writer.Write((uint)Source.Length);

    int count;
    while ( (count=Source.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length))>0)
        file.Write(buffer, 0, count);

    // append custom data here ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you have a look at [Wix](http://wixtoolset.org/). Wix is open source, so if you are desparate to write some installer code, you can contribute to the Wix source. Wix also allows you to write your own custom actions, in C# if preferred. Plus it is heavily xml based (generally your installer is a bunch of xml files), so it seems to meet your needs very well.

Comment: What if I don't want to rely on an existing solution? I'm more interested in the theoretical way of how such a task is accomplished.

Answer (score 1):

One simplistic way is to have a program that takes a standard executable and appends your data to it after the normal end of file (with a "magic word"). What that "standard executable" does is simply read itself, find the magic word that marks the beginning of data and extract that data. There are definitely other, more elegant ways, especially with newer languages and runtimes, but the one I mentioned is something basic that can be implemented even in plain C.

Alternatively, with .NET, you can utilize the runtime compiler to create your executable on the fly from stock code and I think you can also embed resources, like you embed resources in your VS projects. I'm not 100% positive on this one, though.

Comment: I am using VS2012, but I haven't discovered an option regards to this task yet.

Comment: Sorry, mentioning VS2012 was a poor choice of words before. I should have said .NET Framework. See my edit.